# Can we connect a mongodb server and a mysql server available on same host using a single PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, server

I want to update mongodb document on basis of selected data from mysql table inside the same php file. Kindly share how this could be achieved.

Comment: Yes you can. Since SO is not a free coding service: what have you tried so far or at least researched so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i don't misunderstand you:

```php
<?php
$mysqlDb = connectToMysql(); // fake code to connect to mysql
$mongoDb = connectToMongod(); // fake code to connect to mongodb
$data = $mysqlDb->getData(); // fake code to get data from mysql
$mongoDb->update($data); // fake code to update mongodb
```